# What types of lat/long coordinates are these?

Tags: latitude-longitude, mapping

I'm trying to map out a set of coordinates that I received:

```
 N 39,21.440 W 120,48.076
```

But i'm not familiar with the format.  I'm familiar with DMS lat/longs and the standard(?) format (eg, 39.123234, -121.348348)

Can anyone tell me how I can convert these to either DMS or standard?

Comment: Looks like degrees and decimal minutes?

Comment: If you (or anyone else) has a similar question in the future: it is really helpful to add what the expected domain of the coordinates is. If all the coordinates are expected to be within a single country (or a state or whatever) it might be a system local to that place, while coordinates that could possibly lie anywhere in the world are a completely different hint at a world-wide coordinate system.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are likely "Degrees, Decimal Minutes".

**Conversion to Decimal Degrees**

You can convert it to "Decimal Degrees" by diving the "Decimal Minutes" by 60 and adding the result to the Degrees:

```
21.440 / 60 = .3573333333 + 39 = N 39.3573333333 

48.076 / 60 = .8012666666 + 120 = W 120.8012666666
```

**Conversion to Degrees Minutes Seconds**

Or you can convert to "Degrees Minutes Seconds" by multiplying the fractional side of the "Decimal Minutes" by 60 to get the Seconds:

```
21.44 = .440 * 60 = 26.4 = N 39 21 26.4

48.076 = .076 * 60 = 4.56 = W 120 48 4.56
```

Comment: "Adding" to the degrees **before** assigning the proper sign -- W120 should be -120 in DD.

Comment: I was trying to keep it too simple... I edited my answer to include the W